# Why does this animation not work. css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Alright so when i have this code the animation works, but the image is in the wrong position:

```
#myAnimationUp {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>up.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:55px; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:30px;
  bottom:1px; 
  right: 30px;
}
```

So i imagined, pulling the image down with css would do the job since bottom would display the image higher then using this code:

```
#myAnimationUp {
  background-image: url("images/ships/ship<?php echo $_SESSION['getshiptype']; ?>up.png");
  background-size:     cover;                      
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  height:55px; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:30px;
  top:35px; 
  right: 30px;
}
```

With the code above the image is in the correct position, but the animation doesn't happen anymore. The image stays where it is unlike the most upper code where the animation does work.

Animation code:

```
<script>
  function myMoveUp() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimationUp");   
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    Clock.pause();
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 105) {
        clearInterval(id);
        Clock.resume();
        keymanager.resume();
      } else {
        pos++; 
        elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
        keymanager.suspend();
      }
    }
    MoveShip();
  }
</script>
```

I have taken 2 screenshots to help understand whats going on:

screenshot1

[image: screenshot1]

screenshot2

[image: screenshot2]

In screenshot 1 you can see that the ship is positioned in grid C4.

In screenshot 2 you can see the ship facing north, but not in grid C4, but in B4.

This only happens when i use bottom:1px; in the css. At this time the animation works. When i use top:35px; to get the image in grid C4 the animation doesn't work anymore.

What is causing this and how do i fix it?

Comment: give relative position to the parent and absolute to child so it don't cross box limit

Comment: that fixed it. thanks